# Marble probability question with combinations and calculator

Tags: probability, combinations

She has seen a bag containing three red marbles, four green ones, five white ones, and two purple ones. She grabs five of them. Find the probability of the following event, expressing it as a fraction in lowest terms. She has two red ones and one of each of the other colors.

Can someone explain to me how to solve this problem in the calculator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the number of marbles be: $r$ for red, $g$ for green, $w$ for white and $p$ for purple. Then, your desired probability will be
$$
\frac{\binom{r}{2}\binom{g}{1}\binom{w}{1}\binom{p}{1}}{\binom{r+g+w+p}{5}}=\frac{\binom{3}{2}\binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{1}\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{3+4+5+2}{5}}=\frac{3\times 4\times 5\times 2}{\frac{14!}{5!\times 9!}}
$$
So, now you have to perform the cancellations.

Answer (score 2):

**Basic approach.** How many different ways are there to pick $5$ marbles (at random, presumably) from a total of $3+4+5+2 = 14$?  Call this number $N$.  How many ways are there to pick $2$ of the $3$ red marbles, $1$ of the $4$ green ones, $1$ of the $5$ white ones, and $1$ of the $2$ purple ones?  Call this number $M$.  Then the probability is just $M/N$.

Comment: Since OP asked for "solving with a calculator", @user344249 should check the $C_n^k$ ($n$ take $k$) function. That's the shortcut for calculator. Otherwise, use the definition for combinations.